# Switched OS version, vulkan program stopped working

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, vulkan

A program I was developing stopped working when I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04

What I suspect is happening is, I am using conan to install dependencies, including what would be inside the sdk (the loader, the headers, the validation layers).

vkcube and vulkaninfo run, so vulkan itself is fine.

The conan package versions (whose versioning matches that of the official github repos for each project) are:

```
    "vulkan-headers/1.2.184",
    "vulkan-loader/1.2.182",
    "vulkan-validationlayers/1.2.182"
```

I get the following from vulkaninfo:

```
vulkaninfo | grep Instance
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.182
Instance Extensions: count = 18
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
        maxMultiviewInstanceIndex = 2147483647
        maxMultiviewInstanceIndex         = 2147483647
        drawIndirectFirstInstance               = true
        vertexAttributeInstanceRateDivisor     = true
        vertexAttributeInstanceRateZeroDivisor = true
        drawIndirectFirstInstance               = true
        vertexAttributeInstanceRateDivisor     = true
        vertexAttributeInstanceRateZeroDivisor = false
```

I have also tried downloading the latest sdk and running the setu-env.sh script to see if that fixes it but it doesn't seem to do anything.

The exact problem I get is, a segmentation fault when calling:
`physical_device.getQueueFamilyProperties();` (I am using the .hpp header)

I am not entirely sure why things stopped working, I suspect I might have a mismatch between, for example my vulkan.hpp header and my vulkan library but I don't know how to check. And I am not sure it is actually the problem.

I get this as well when running `vulkaninfo | grep GPU`:

```sh
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
        GPU id = 0 (AMD RADV RAVEN2 (ACO))
        GPU id = 1 (llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits))
        GPU id = 0 (AMD RADV RAVEN2 (ACO))
        GPU id = 1 (llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits))
GPU id : 0 (AMD RADV RAVEN2 (ACO)):
GPU id : 1 (llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)):
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
GPU0:
    deviceType     = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_GPU
GPU1:
```

Comment: which MESA version? IT looks like it stopped using GPU.  CHeck what `vulkaninfo | grep GPU` says. `llvmpipe` one is not what you want, it seems.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I added it, I don't seem to find anything related to mesa. I do get this:
`driverInfo         = Mesa 21.0.3 (ACO)` if I grep for Mesa instead of GPU

Comment: MESA is you graphics back end, and 20.1 +, to which you had upgraded, got device selection layer for Vulkan. Apparently currently a wrong device is selected (1 instead of 0 in your case, order in `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` is _random_). Check MESA_VK_DEVICE_SELECT to begin with

Comment: Sorry, checking it where? I tried to grep that on both vulkaninfo and printenv and both come out empty. (thank you for your help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reddit comment seems to have been the solution:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/krz20h/vulkan_swrast_lavapipe_is_getting_used_instead_of/

specifically:

> After reading through Archwiki, I've discovered that lavapipe is indeed being used instead of radeon.
> exporting VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json fixes the issue.